# How to select multiple features by drawing a line or polygon in openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to select features by drawing some geometries, if the `line` or `polygon` has touched or enclosed the feature, the `feature` should be selected？ If someone has ideas for it？

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at turf: http://turfjs.org

You can build this functionality with help of its api: After a line or polygon has been drawn, analyze the data with turfs api. Then select the features according to this analysis

Comment: hmm it looks good, but i dont know how to use the api, i dont if they have some script example or demo.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more precise. I'm not an open layers guru and not working with it right now. Since the API had changed a lot, I'd better not try.